# Writing a Simple Image Publisher (C++) tutorial Segmentation Fault

Tags: ros, opencv, image, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running ROS Kinetic full desktop install on Raspberrypi 3b running Debian Jessie.  These are fresh installs with nothing else added.  I followed the Simple Image Publisher/Subscriber tutorials and can successful compile.  When I run my_publisher (c++) I get a Segmentation Fault.  If I start up python on the command and do "import cv2" I get a Segmentation Fault.  I suspect the two are related.  I have all the dependencies, cv_bridge, vision_opencv.  I also see cv2.so in /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages.

I am unclear if I need to install opencv on my own or if it is part of the ROS install.  But if it isn't part of the install, why do I have a cv2.so in my ros directory?   I have done a complete sd card reformat and fresh install of Jessie and then the ROS desktop install multiple times and I keep getting the same result.  I have tried catkin packages and ros-packages.  Can anyone give me some pointers?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248912/writing-a-simple-image-publisher-(c++)-tutorial-segmentation-fault/) by [FAD0](https://answers.ros.org/users/28595/fad0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2016-11-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-27**:
Any time you run into `SEGFAULT`s, run the binary (preferably a version with debug symbols) in `gdb` and after getting the `SEGFAULT`, get `gdb` to print a backtrace for you (`bt`).

Please add one of the tutorial C++ node you mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured out the problem.  I was publishing a jpeg file but had not installed the image_transport_plugins, so it couldn't handle the jpeg format.  Once I installed the plugins it worked.

---

Originally posted by [FAD0](https://answers.ros.org/users/28595/fad0/) with karma: 16 on 2016-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-29**:
Not having some plugins around on the system should not result in `SEGFAULT`s, warnings / errors at most. Could you report this over at the `image_transport` [issue tracker](https://github.com/ros-perception/image_common/issues)?

**Comment by [FAD0](https://answers.ros.org/users/28595/fad0/) on 2016-12-01**:
gvdhoorn: I am very new to ROS.  There were too many possible things I could have been doing wrong in my environment to know if it was the lack of the proper plugins that was causing the segfault. So I consider this user error.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-01**:
You may be new, but we should make sure that plugin discovering / loading code does not cause crashes when no plugins are present on a system. That's why I feel it's important to report this.